# SQL bulk insert in window service c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, permissions, windows-services, sqlbulkcopy

I have one window service in c#.In this I want to bulk insert into database table. The code like following:

```
    SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection(Common.RepositoryCN);

     _con.Open();

    DataTable dsField = objDbOpertaions.GetFields(Id);

    if (dsField != null)

    {

    using (SqlBulkCopy sbc = new qlBulkCopy(_con))
{                                        
sbc.DestinationTableName = fileName.Insert(0, "DP_");

for (int j = 0; j < dsField.Rows.Count; j++)

{

sbc.ColumnMappings.Add(dsField.Rows[j][0].ToString(), dsField.Rows[j][1].ToString());

}

 try
 {     
  sbc.WriteToServer(dtTable); //here

   LoggerMessage.LogMessage(System.DateTime.Now + fileName + "Bulk insert into database.");

  }
  catch (Exception ex)
   {
   sw = new StreamWriter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Log.txt", true);
                                                sw.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now + ex.Message+"-New error in bulk insert.");
   sw.Flush();
   sw.Close();
   sbc.Close();

    }
   finally
   {
    sbc.Close();
    _con.Close();
    }
 }
```

here when bulk insert exception throwing which get in log.txt file like

**5/30/2015 11:35:54 AM Cannot access destination table 'DP_WCRJZE'.-New error in bulk insert.**

Now for testing I give my table name statically i.e

> DP_WCRJZE

then it works and insert bulk into table but when I pass it like

> fileName.Insert(0, "DP_")
>   then only giving error.
>   I also print the string which is pass dynamically which is same as static given.

What is Problem?
Any solution for this?

Comment: Are you able to use regular insert? Are you able to use bulk insert with a single record?

Comment: What is dtTable  here and where have you defined this ?

Comment: dtTable is data table's instance which defined globally and i can't bulk insert with one record also.

Comment: Also can you clearify this line `fileName.Insert(0, "DP_");`

Comment: in my table table name like DP_table1 In fileName i got table1 so I replace with DP_table1

Comment: Do you have a table named DP_WCRJZE in database ?

Comment: yes.I have this table name.

Comment: Show that table in question.

Comment: You have any solution for this???